# Continuously Expanding Widget

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt6

I've been working on a small project of mine and discovered this interesting behavior.

If I execute the `clickable_image.py` alone, everything works fine. The image stays only as large that it fits the window and leaves blank space above and below or to the sides depending on the size of the window in relation to the image size.
If I execute the `image_tile.py` file with the `ImageTile` as the root widget, the window continuously expands to the side.
Now if I wrap the `ImageTile` in a `QMainWindow` and use that as the root widget, everything behaves normal again (like when I ran the `clickable_image.py` file)

I know that I can always circumvent the problem by always having a `QMainWindow` as the root widget but I'm very curious to know why this happens.

Another interesting observation I made, adding a `setFixedWidth(some_number)` to the `ImageTile` without a `QMainWindow` as root, solves the problem of expanding, however, I can no longer resize the window.
If use `setMaxWidth(some_number)` instead, the Windows overruns the constraint and keeps continuously expanding.

If anyone could explain how this behavior is produced, I'd be delighted.

Thank you for your help.

AliSot2000

Maybe relevant, I'm using Kubuntu 20.04 on AMD x86_64 with an NVIDIA GPU

**clibkable_image.py**

```py
import os.path
import warnings
import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QLabel, QPushButton, QApplication
from PyQt6.QtGui import QPixmap, QIcon
from typing import Union

class ClickableImage(QPushButton):
    img_lbl: QLabel
    pixmap: Union[QPixmap, None]
    fpath: str
    width_div_height: float = 1.0
    count: int = 0

    def __init__(self, file_path: str):
        super().__init__()
        self.pixmap = None
        self.load_image(file_path)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        super().resizeEvent(event)
        self.setIconSize(event.size())
       
    def load_image(self, file_path: str):
        self.fpath = file_path
        self.pixmap = QPixmap(file_path)


        try:
            self.width_div_height = self.pixmap.width() / self.pixmap.height()
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            self.width_div_height = 1.0
        self.setIcon(QIcon(self.pixmap))
        self.setIconSize(self.size())
        self.setStyleSheet("border: none;")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = ClickableImage('PATH/TO/SOME/IMAGE')
    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

**image_tile.py**

```py
import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QSizePolicy, QMainWindow
from clickable_image import ClickableImage
import os


class ImageTile(QLabel):
    def __init__(self, path: str):
        super().__init__()

        # self.setMaximumWidth(1000)

        self.file_path = path
        self.file_nane_lbl = QLabel()
        self.file_nane_lbl.setText(os.path.basename(self.file_path))
        self.image = ClickableImage(self.file_path)
        self.image.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Policy.MinimumExpanding, QSizePolicy.Policy.MinimumExpanding)

        self.b_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.b_layout.addWidget(self.image)
        self.b_layout.addWidget(self.file_nane_lbl)
        self.setLayout(self.b_layout)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        super().resizeEvent(event)

    def heightForWidth(self, a0: int) -> int:
        return self.width()

class CustomMain(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setCentralWidget(ImageTile('PATH/TO/SOME/IMAGE'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    # widget = ImageTile('PATH/TO/SOME/IMAGE')
    widget = CustomMain()
    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main cause of your problem is that you are calling `setIconSize()` within a `resizeEvent()`, which is a *terrible* idea.

Even if you're ignoring the border with the QSS, by default a QPushButton always adds a horizontal margin of 4 pixels to the sides of the icon. This results in an infinite recursion for the `resizeEvent()`: calling `self.setIconSize()` makes the minimum size hint of the button equal to the icon width *plus* the 4 pixels.

You do not see the effect in the case of QMainWindow because in that case the widget is not a top level window any more, so its size hints obey to the rules of the layout manager: you are also using a QLabel subclass, which is quite a peculiar widget that has dynamic size hint "rules" and, if it has no text specified, always returns an invalid minimum size hint, allowing it to be resized to a size smaller than its contents. The layout, if any is set, is **completely** ignored when returning the size hint to the container.

If you change the class inheritance from QLabel to QWidget, you will see the same problem even in the case of QMainWindow.

So, first of all, as a rule of thumb you shall *never* do changes that could alter the size of the widget within a `resizeEvent()`, unless you **really** know what you're doing.

Doing so with `setIconSize()` would be wrong anyway, because setting the icon size means that the widget then has minimum size restraints that could (theoretically) prevent it to become smaller. It would be like calling `setMinimumSize(event.size())` within the `resizeEvent()`.

If what you want to achieve is a "clickable image", then the only *proper* way is to just subclass QWidget, override the `paintEvent()` to draw the image while keeping its aspect ratio, and also add a custom signal that would be emitted in the `mouseReleaseEvent()`.

```py
class ClickableImage(QWidget):
    clicked = pyqtSignal()
    pixmap = None
    def __init__(self, file_path: str):
        super().__init__()
        self.load_image(file_path)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.clicked.emit()

    def load_image(self, file_path: str):
        self.fpath = file_path
        self.pixmap = QPixmap(file_path)
        self.updateGeometry()
        if not self.pixmap.isNull() and self.isVisible():
            self.update()

    def sizeHint(self):
        if self.pixmap and not self.pixmap.isNull():
            return self.pixmap.size()
        return QSize()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        if not self.pixmap or self.pixmap.isNull():
            return
        if self.size() == self.pixmap.size():
            r = self.rect()
        else:
            r = QRect(QPoint(), 
                self.pixmap.size().scaled(self.size(), Qt.KeepAspectRatio))
            r.moveCenter(self.rect().center())
        qp = QPainter(self)
        qp.drawPixmap(r, self.pixmap)
```

If you need a container, **never** use QLabel.

If you want styling features, subclass from QFrame, otherwise use a basic QWidget.